# A for/while/if program to create a vector of repeated elements

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, vectorization

My task is to write a program to create a vector which has its first 10 elements to be 10, element 11-20 to be 20, element 21-30 to be 30, element 31-40 to be 40, & element 41-50 to be 50.

This is how i did it.

```
v=zeros(1,50);
for i = 1:10 
    v(i)=10;
end
for i =11:20
    v(i)=20;
end
for i = 21:30
    v(i)=30;
end
for i = 31:40
    v(i)=40;
end
for i = 41:50
    v(i)=50
end
```

How can I write this more efficiently? (I'm new to matlab and programming in general. I'm thinking about how to construct this using `while` or `if` loops instead but without being able to produce a more efficient code.)

Comment: I would repmat the vector `[10:10:50]` to create 10 rows of that vector and then reshape it into a row vector: `reshape(repmat((10:10:50), 10, 1), 1, [])`

Comment: Very algebraic, and most probably less efficient than Suever's solution, but still... `v = reshape(10*ones(10,1)*(1:5),1,[]);`

Comment: Another option is something like `v=floor(1:0.1:5.9)*10;`, which is slightly more efficient, though less readable.

Comment: Just a note to help you understand the comments: If you want to be more efficient with Matlab, AVOID loops, and prefer vectorization.

Comment: @F88 please consider accepting on of the answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As we're spit-balling ways of doing this, something a bit different (though likely not efficient):

```
v=sort(mod(10:10:500,50))+10;
```

Also a method similar to rayryeng's answer, though I think slightly more efficient (avoiding the call to `bsxfun`):

```
v = 10:10:50;
v = v(ones(10,1),:);
v = v(:)';
```

Comment: Using `bsxfun` on small inputs is indeed less efficient. You see it work better as the size of the inputs get bigger.

Comment: the `sort` way is very very awkward, but the second solution is elegant!

Comment: @Shai Yes, the `sort` method was never intended to be taken seriously, it was more an academic exercise to see how many ways I could think of to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
v = zeros(1,50);
v(1:10:end) = 10;
v = cumsum(v)
```

---

Using [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
v = kron(10:10:50,ones(1,10))
```

---

If you like `mod`ulo operations, you can

```
v = reshape( mod(reshape((0:49)',[5 10]),5)'+1, 1, [] )*10
```

I suppose it's a bit more efficient that `sort`+`mod` proposed by [@MrAzzaman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39888884/1714410).

Answer (score 2):

The solutions in the comments as well as Shai's are very good.  This is primarily here for thinking outside of the box.  A more exotic solution would be to use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), followed by unrolling the resulting matrix into a vector:

```
v = bsxfun(@times, 10:10:50, ones(10,1));
v = v(:).';
```

Comment: I'm always in favour of bsxfun. BTW, you should have 10 ones instead of 5

Comment: @Shai Aha, I missed that.  Thank you.  I will correct.

Answer (score 2):

The dedicated function for this task *since Matlab R2015a* is [**`repelem`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
x = repelem(10:10:50,10)
```

and another alternative:

```
s = 10; m = 50;
x = meshgrid(s:s:m,ones(s,1))
x = x(:)
```